# List of Rcpp sugar functions?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm just getting started with Rcpp and wondering if somewhere out there a list of Rcpp sugar functions exists.  In the process of translating some of my slow code to C/C++ I'll need functionality provided by base R functions like `match`, `tabulate`, and `which`.

According to [Hadley's Advanced R book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html#rcpp-sugar) `match` is implemented and the [Rcpp-sugar vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-sugar.pdf) lists a few more available functions though it doesn't seem comprehensive.

What I'm really wondering is: is there a way to find, in the documentation of the package, or elsewhere, what sweet-sweet-sweet functions are available and what I'll have to write for myself? With any other R package I'd go directly to `R> help(package = "Rcpp")` but that doesn't seem to be much help in this case.

Comment: Have a look at the source https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/tree/master/inst/include/Rcpp/sugar

Comment: Hooray! Table is in there! Thanks @mnel.

Answer (score 16):

As luck would have it, I started to document the Rcpp API in a more accessible manner than what is offered by the doxygen documentation. This documentation includes the *Rcpp sugar* set of functions alongside usable examples. I'm hopeful that Rcpp should ship with this documentation in the 0.13.0.

In the interim, you can view the source and contribute here:

https://github.com/coatless/rcpp-api/blob/master/rcpp-api-docs.Rmd

Or view a rendered version (that is lagged) here:

http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/rcpp/unofficial-rcpp-api-docs/

Comment: Awesome, this was really missing so far.